# Complicated regex_match not working in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to do some input validation for a time in the format

```
"1:00 to 12:59 and AM/PM"
```

I created this regex:`\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) *([AaPp][Mm]))`.
I tested it at regexr.com and it worked fine.

However, when I try to do something like:

```
std::string s ("1:00 AM");
std::regex e ("\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) *([AaPp][Mm]))");

if (std::regex_match (s,e))
  std::cout << "string object matched\n";
```

It never works. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: How about this? `([0-1]?[0-2]:[0-5][0-9]\s*[AaPp][Mm])`

Comment: Doesn't work. Not sure why. Your regex works fine on regexr.com though! Does it maybe have something to do with the escape characters? Cause here for
    \s you have to escape it with   
\\s?

Comment: thanks @MYGz it worked just by changing \s* to space*. Maybe it had to do with the escape characters inside a string.

Comment: take a look at raw string literals (http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings), no need for awkward escaping in regex strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @MYGz I was able to fix this. Maybe it had something to do with escape characters.

All I did to change @MYGz's suggestion was to remove the \s.

It worked with `([0-1]?[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] *[AaPp][Mm])`

Comment: `([0-1]?[0-2]:[0-5]\d *[AaPp][Mm])` 3 characters less :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a raw string literal `R` for using single `\`. You can try like so:

```
R"(?!0:00|00:00)([0-1]?[0-2]:[0-5]\d\s*[AaPp][Mm])"
```

`(?!0:00|00:00)` - Negative look ahead for 0:00 or 00:00 without consuming.

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/t7Oa0Q/2